# Laravel Collection is empty

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to learn more about Laravel ORM and ORM in general,
but I have problems I can't solve by myself.

This is my users table: [image]

And here is my Article table: [image]

My User eloquent model:

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{

    /**
    * The table associated with the model.
    *
    * @var string
    */

    protected $table = 'users';

    public function article()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\Article', 'autor_id');
    }


}
```

And my Article eloquent model:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{

    /**
    * The table associated with the model.
    *
    * @var string
    */

    protected $table = 'clanky';

    public function autor() {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\User', 'id');
    }



}
```

I am trying to access each article with its author data using this code:

```php
$articles = Models\Article::all();

foreach($articles as $art)
{
    echo $art->autor->name . "<br>";
}
```

The problem is the model is returning only userdata from first article, not the second and so on.
Any thoughts on what could cause this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to set the foreign key in your belongs relation : `belongsTo('\App\Models\User', 'autor_id');` according to documetation : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse

Comment: Couple clarifications: *"Laravel Collection returns NULL"* - `Collection`s aren't `null`, they can be `empty`, but not `null`. Next, `$art->autor` does not return a `Collection`, it should be a `User` or `null`. Also, `public function article()` should be `public function articles()`, since it is returning a `hasMany()`. I'd double check your relationships; you're linking your `belongsTo()` on `id`, but I think that should be `autor_id`

Comment: I concur with Tim's assessment. I had typed out nearly the exact same comment when yours popped up, Tim! :)

Comment: All of the above... and I'll throw in another - do you have `$fillable` for your fields on your model?  That would also cause a few problems.

Comment: @Vince Haha yeah, I see these misconceptions a lot; it's not an error per-say, but realizing what a `Collection` is, vs a `Model` or `Builder` instance is key to debugging Laravel. And function names help identify what something is before you call it, so mixing plural and singular can waste time. @Watercayman Not sure what issues omitting `$fillable` would have for this specific case; there's no instances of `Model::create()` in this code, so it shouldn't have any bearing.

Comment: I feel like I shouldn't answer this, can I post an answer with a correct sample migration?

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks a lot. I had wrong linkings changed `id` to `autor_id` and i got the results i expected.

Comment: As suspected. Makes sense that it would work for one of them as well; `articles.id` could match one of the `users.id` columns. @VincentDecaux you should convert your comment to an answer; you've got the correct information on how to fix.

Comment: @Tim - true, no create in the question... was just wondering if maybe there *was* only one record entered by test and thus couldn't add more due to no mass assignment.  Was thinking more that he said he was new to Laravel, and I didn't see it in the code, hoping to help him in a potentially unrelated way as well.

Comment: @Watercayman Ah gotcha; I can see the logic in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to update your code like.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{

    /**
    * The table associated with the model.
    *
    * @var string
    */

    protected $table = 'Article';

    public function autor() {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\User', 'autor_id', 'id');
    }



}

$articles = Models\Article::with('autor')->get();

foreach($articles as $art)
{
    echo $art->autor->name . "<br>";
}
```